# can't call webmethod from jquery data source

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm trying to populate a jqxgrid with data from SQL Server. I'm following all the instruction jqwedgets stated to get data from SQL Server, but for some reason nothing is happening. The grid shows empty with no data.

I'm using this code:

Script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
var url = "/test.aspx/Getquestions";

// prepare the data
var source = {
    datatype: "xml",
    datafields: [{ name: 'QuestionID' },
                 { name: 'QuestionText' },
                 { name: 'NumberofAnswers' }],
    async: false,
    record: 'question',
    url: url
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
});
```

C# code

i tried to call the webservice from the browser directly but is giving me 404 error. here is the web service class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace CIS
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET     AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    //[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)] 
    public  string Getquestions()
    {
        return "hello";

    }
}
}
```

the webmethod is not being called at all.
I tested the webmethod function and it works. it creates the xml. but for some reason the url property is not calling the webmethod. any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to remove `static` from your method definition.

`public string Getquestions()`

If that doesn't work I'd suggest using a network traffic analyzer like Fiddler or Wireshark to confirm the web request is being sent.

Comment: i removed the static from the method, but still is not working. i also tried Fiddler, and it is telling me that there is 404 error when calling the method. ami calling it in a wrong way

Comment: @mohamedbaradie - Perhaps. What kind of file is this C# code you've posted in? Also can you show the class that contains this method? Also can you tell me what HTTP verb is being used when the request is made? The verb should be visible on the Fiddler traffic.

Comment: i tried to call the webservice from the browser directly but is giving me 404 error. edit the question with the entire class

Comment: @mohamedbaradie - Are you sure your file is test.aspx and not test.asmx?

Comment: actually it is call webservice1.asmx and i changed the url to be like this. but actually when try to invoke the webservice from the browser it gives me 404 error